# Trying to understand if I need to give domain-wide authority to my appengine service account so that it can access data on Google Drive

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have an appengine app that stores documents in a Google Docs account. It uses the Documents List API to communicate with Google Docs but I am now trying to migrate it to use the Drive API as the Documents List API is supposed to be shutdown on 4/20.

I would like to know if I need to grant any special permissions for my appengine app to be able to access the Drive account and read/write documents from it. i.e., do I need to add a row on this screen?
[image]

The Google Docs account under which files are stored by my current app is of the form `user@xyz.com` where `xyz.com` is a domain name that I purchased through Google and that is aliased to my appengine app. Further `user@xyz.com` is an owner of my appengine app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

[Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation)

- In the Client name field enter the service account's Client ID.
- In the One or More API Scopes field enter the list of scopes that your application should be granted access to (see image below). For example if you need domain-wide access to the Google Drive API and the Google Calendar API enter: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
- Click the Authorize button.
  Your service account now has domain-wide access to the Google Drive API for all the users of your domain, and potentially the other APIs you’ve listed such as the Calendar API in the example above. You are ready to instantiate an authorized Drive service Object on behalf of your Google Apps domain's users.

[image]

When you make the calls, you will have to impersonate the user whose account you want to access, i.e. `user@xyz.com`

Comment: what should be the client ID? is it supposed to be myapp.appspot.com where myapp should be replaced by my google appengine application identifier?

Comment: @morpheus added a picture, you find the client Id with the service account information.

Comment: Thanks. that clientID is a manually created clientID. The appengine app comes with a built-in service account. I think its clientID will be myapp.appspot.com. will try it out and see if that works.

Comment: yes, i can access user data from a non-GAE app but running into some issues trying to access user data from a GAE app using the **built-in service account**, not a manually created one.